# how to add login for different roles in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three models A,B and C and their associations are A has_many B,C and B,C belong_to A. I created login and authentication for 'A' by referring Michael hartl book. when A logs in, he organises B and C (create,update and destroy B and C).
Now I want a login and authentication for B. when B logins he redirect to another page.

To achieve this I tried to add roles to A and B using cancan gem but I got stuck how to use login page of A for B to log in and redirect. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for authentication, you can use the `after_sign_in_path_for` hook, as described in [the documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/Helpers:after_sign_in_path_for). In this method you can define the logic the application should follow in order to redirect the logged-in user to one page or another one.

In addition, you should take into account that some users cannot access certain pages, and that is where [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) gem makes sense. No matter the redirect configuration you set up, you should prevent unauthorized users from visiting certain pages.